# Getting reference for a inner control in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am new in android and I have read some tutos about custom ListView and I am doing an app to manipulate data I resume my problem with this litte app. the screen is this: [image]

in this there are a listview and each item have a TextView and a EditText the one last control is for the user input a amount I need when the user press the button clear first save de amount info in the arraylist and then clear the fields. how I approach this 
my code:
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.rimacy.preguntalistview.MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:id="@+id/btnClear"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

listview_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="item"
        android:id="@+id/tv1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Input amount"
        android:id="@+id/edit1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.rimacy.preguntalistview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArrayList<Inventory> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(new Inventory("candies",0));
        data.add(new Inventory("milk",0));
        data.add(new Inventory("soda",0));
        data.add(new Inventory("paper",0));
        data.add(new Inventory("bags",0));
        //... the items are unknow in run time

        MyAdapter adp = new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_item,data);
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(adp);

        Button btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // set de value of each EditText to "amount" field in each object in the ArrayList "data"
                // perform a clear of all EditText in the listview
                // set the focus in the firs EditText
            }
        });


    }
    class Inventory{
        String name;
        Integer amount;

        public Inventory(String name, Integer amount) {
            this.name = name;
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
    class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Inventory>{
        private ArrayList<Inventory> items;
        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Inventory> items) {
            super(context, resource, items);
            this.items = items;
        }
        public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v=convertView;
            TextView editText;
            if (v == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater =  LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
            }
            editText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            editText.setText(items.get(position).getName());
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

**update**
I do this

**

```
package com.rimacy.preguntalistview;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Inventory> data = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        data.add(new Inventory("candies",0));
        data.add(new Inventory("milk",0));
        data.add(new Inventory("soda",0));
        data.add(new Inventory("paper",0));
        data.add(new Inventory("bags",0));
        //... the items are unknow in run time
        final MyAdapter adp = new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_item,data);
        final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(adp);
        adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Button btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        if (btnClear!= null){
            btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // set de value of each EditText to "amount" field in each object in the ArrayList "data"
                    // perform a clear of all EditText in the listview
                    // set the focus in the firs EditText
                    for (Inventory i:data){
                        i.getTxt().setText("");
                    }
                    adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    class Inventory{
        String name;
        Integer amount;
        EditText txt;
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public EditText getTxt() {
            return txt;
        }
        public void setTxt(EditText txt) {
            this.txt = txt;
        }
        public Inventory(String name, Integer amount) {
            this.name = name;
            this.amount = amount;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
    class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Inventory>{
        private ArrayList<Inventory> items;
        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Inventory> items1) {
            super(context, resource, items1);
            items = items1;
        }
        public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v=convertView;
            TextView editText;
            EditText txt;
            if (v == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater =  LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
            }
            txt = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
            editText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            items.get(position).setTxt(txt);
            editText.setText(items.get(position).getName());
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

added a new member in the Inventory Class to store a reference of the editText wich is assigned in the getView event and with the getTxt methos recall this reference and call the setText method with empty string but it only works when I press the button for twice time why??

Comment: Store the edittext values in a hash map.

Comment: I do with a new member but dont work as it mus be, I try it with a hashmap but occurs the same it only work when press for second time the button

Comment: I didn't see you use the getTxt() method of the Inventor class anywhere in your code? Why are you exactly storing an EditText view rather than the string there in ? I think you have mistakenly used the EditText itself rather than storing the user entered value which you can get by editText().getText().toString().

Comment: I do this to store a reference because I use this in the onclick method of the button to manipulate(clearing his content) in the gui

Comment: I want to clear the values besides to candies milk soda...